# Listening to Trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a library that when complete will trigger an event via `$(document).trigger('playlistDone');`. I am listening to this trigger but I am not getting the `alert()` I am expecting.

```
$(document).bind('playlistDone', function() {
   alert('done');
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We need more info. What library? Are you sure that it is triggering `playlistDone`?

Comment: The only way this can happen with the code you've posted is if another event listener is on the `document`, which is handled *before* your's, and is calling `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

Comment: @Shmiddty Sorry, this is a custom library another coworker has written which is retrieves all the video IDs from a Youtube playlist. I am sure it is triggering `playlistDone`.

Comment: How are you binding it? How is it being triggered? Add a break point where it is being triggered to make sure it is being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, as of jQuery 1.7 the preferred method for attaching events is `on`, not `bind` (see http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Second, your basic syntax looks ok, but it's important to understand you're dealing with *custom* events, not *browser* events.  This means that your library must be using jQuery to trigger its event, or else jQuery won't detect it when it happens.

Comment: I'll modify my code to use `on()`. How would I check if my library is using jQUery to trigger the event?

Comment: Well, one simple way is to go in to your jQuery code, find the "trigger" function and add a console.log('hey!') or debugger line, then load things up and see if your library triggers that line.

Comment: Hmm... the console.log() didn't display anything. I'm going to say something is wrong with the library.

Comment: Sounds about right.  You may want to double check their documentation to see if it mentions anything about telling the library where your jQuery is; if they're expecting you to say "here's my jQuery var" and you're not, so they fallback to their own, separate, jQuery, you might get the problem you're having ... then again, it could just be a bad library.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). From jQuery documentation :

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method
>   provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.

Try something like that:

```
$(document).on('playlistDone', function( a ) {
   alert( a );
});
```

and

```
var data = 'Done';
$(document).trigger('playlistDone', data );
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the code associated with `trigger()` goes inside the library.